# Displaying server-side model-state errors on client side via ajax in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, error-handling

Scenario:

I invoke controller action of MVC4 web application via jquery $.ajax({...}) call and pass details about user I wish to save.
Web application connects to back-end private API and sends user data, and API returns response indicating that Username is already in use.
I want to display property state error on property Username in a place where regular client-side validation error message would appear.

Currently I do it manually but I'm wondering if there is jQuery compatible library that would render property-state errors for me in a way that I provide key/value errors as response from action, and library handles the rest.

Answer (score 0):

you can render a new partial view along with model state erros ( use ModelState.AddModelError in controller).